# When I send a GET request : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

when I tried to send a get request to the url of my function (on a firebase project ex: http://project_url.com/api/post/id), this error shows

```
 (node:1061) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
>      at ServerResponse.header (/Users/salvatorebramante/beta/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
>      at ServerResponse.send (/Users/salvatorebramante/beta/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>      at ServerResponse.json (/Users/salvatorebramante/beta/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>      at /Users/salvatorebramante/beta/functions/handlers/posts.js:70:25
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>  (node:1061) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

The function returns a json with the infos about a document stored in firebase cloud storage

```
exports.getPost = (req,res) => {
    let postData;
    db.doc(`/posts/${req.params.postId}`).get()
    .then(doc =>{
        if(!doc.exists){
            return res.status(404).json({error : 'Post not found'})
        }
        postData = doc.data();
        postData.postId = doc.id;
        return db.collection('comments').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').where('postId','==',req.params.postId).get();
    })
    .then(data =>{
        postId.comments = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
            postData.comments.push(doc.data());
        })
        return res.json(postData);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });             
        console.error(err);                                              
    });  

};
```

While the error occurred, the get request response is 404, but I've checked that the document id is correct. How can I resolve it?

Comment: There's not enough debugging information here for us to be helpful.  We can't see the contents of your database, and we can't see the values of any variables when this code runs.  Please edit the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect and add more details.

Comment: Your second .then is always called, thus sending http headers a second time if the first conditional is true in the first .then. **Logic Error**